# adding / overwriting to dictionary depending on elements

Tags: python, dictionary

py 2.7. I have a dictionary of lists. Each cycle each list is overwritten with a new updated version of itself.

I'm using a third party particle system. What I'm doing is having each key as the particle's index number and the list is of it's position and previous positions.

But when a particle 'dies', the indexes of the particles all get shifted. A key will be overwritten incorrectly when a new particle is born with the same index as the dead particle. I want to preserve that key with positions of the dead particle.

Here's the code as it is now:

```
if frame == 0:
    branches = {}

...

for p in xrange(particle_count):
    xp = emitter.GetParticle(p) #xp = current particle
    trail = []
    index = xp.GetIndex()  
    trail_length = xp.GetCustomDataCount() #number of previous positions

    for i in xrange(trail_length):
        previous_position = xp.GetCustomData(i)
        trail.append(previous_position)
        branches [index] = trail
```

I was thinking of comparing the first element of each list with the first element of the list that it's trying to overwrite. Then if it's different, add 1 to the index number until there's a free spot...?

EDIT - I've made further progress and have identified what I need to do, but don't know the python. Here's some new code:

```
for p in xrange(particle_count):
    xp = emitter.GetParticle(p) #xp = current particle
    trail = []
    index = xp.GetIndex()  
    trail_length = xp.GetCustomDataCount()

    for i in xrange(trail_length):
        previous_position = xp.GetCustomData(i)
        trail.append(previous_position)

    if index in branches:
        this_trail = trail[0]
            set_trail = branches[index]
            set_trail = set_trail[0]

            if this_trail == set_trail:
                branches[index] = trail
            else:
                for b in branches:
                    set_trail = branches[b]
                    set_trail = set_trail[0]
                    if this_trail == set_trail:
                        branches[index] = trail
                        break
     else:
         branches[index] = trail
```

The problem: When I say "if index in branches.." I'm checking each entry for a match. If the trails are the same, the old is overwritten with the new. However, if the index does exist in the dictionary, but is not the same as the entry, nothing will happen. Here's what I need:

```
if index in branches:
    this_trail = trail[0]
    set_trail = branches[index]
    set_trail = set_trail[0]

    if this_trail == set_trail:
        branches[index] = trail
    else:
        check all entries for a match(like i currently do)
        if match, overwrite entry
        if no match, add entry to a non-existing key
else:
    branches[index] = trail
```

Comment: If you are basing some calculations based on this , wouldn't saving in another index (another position) , cause issues later? Can't you just copy the dictionary (and save someplace else) when you see that the particle is dead, and start from a new dictionary?

Comment: Hi Anand. That would make sense. But this point in the code is pretty much the end of the script. All I do after this is take the path of the particle and draw a line on screen like connect the dots. I'm not calling it for anything else later so it doesn't matter.

Comment: So are you facing any issues with the method you specified at the end? What is the actual issue?

Comment: No. Third paragraph, "but when a particle dies..."

Comment: No, I mean with the solution you suggested in  - *I was thinking of comparing the first element of each list with the first element of the list that it's trying to overwrite. Then if it's different, add 1 to the index number until there's a free spot...?*

Comment: What else are you getting?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. I'm not getting any errors. At the end of this there's a ConnectTheDots() function. I do this for each list. In the viewport, 'branches' aka 'trails' will start disappearing shortly after it's particle dies.

Comment: Is it possible that the first element of the list, can be same for some other index for the new particle and the dead prticle?

Comment: It is but that's not what's happening, I can clearly see that.

Comment: I think it's because i'm starting from the middle of the dictionary and only going up instead of checking each key for a match. Stand by...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I get your issue, your code is assuming that Dictionaries are ordered , but they are not, they have arbitrary order, and the actual order really depends on the insertion and deletion history of your dictionary as well as the specific python implementation.

You should not depend on your dictionary being ordered , if you want order in your dictionary, you can try using [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) .

They are similar to normal dictionaries, with the exception that they preserve the order of the elements in them. Example -

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> d[1] = 2
>>> d[5] = 10
>>> d[2] = 11
>>>
>>> d
OrderedDict([(1, 2), (5, 10), (2, 11)])
```

---

Though you may want to rethink whether dictionary is the actual data structure that you want to use. If your indexes are plain numbers, you are better off using a simple list . If they are a tuple of `(x,y)` coordinates, you can use a 2 dimensional list for that.